# Conditional jQuery Toggle Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, logic, toggle

I want to hide and show list items based on their attributed class.

The problem is that certain list items have multiple classes. So if I toggle one class then toggle another, any items with both selected classes will be removed.

I created a demo of my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/a4NkN/2/

Here's the JS CODE:

```
$('#easy').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass( "checked" );
    $('.easy').toggle();
});

$('#fun').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass( "checked" );
    $('.fun').toggle();
});


$('#silly').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass( "checked" );
    $('.silly').toggle();
});
```

If you select the "Easy" and "Fun" buttons, Boating will disappear.

How can I get Boating to stay?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be a good point to start from. Although you can do this cheaper and cleaner, that gives the idea:

Use an array to save the status of your selection buttons and one corresponding to hold the class names. Whenever your select buttons get clicked, you set all your elements invisible and reset those visible again, that are already selected by other buttons or the currently clicked, which is all saved in the switcher array.

```
//saves whether button is active
var switcher = [false, false, false];
//holds your classes selectable
var classes = ['easy', 'fun', 'silly'];

$('.toggler').click(function () {
    // toogle the select button and save status
    var x = $(this).hasClass('checked');
    switcher[$(this).data('switch')] = !x;
    $(this).toggleClass("checked", !x);

    // iterate through your elements to set them active if needed 
    $('li').each(function () {
       var cur = $(this);
       cur.addClass('hidden');
       $.each(switcher, function (index, data) {
          if (data && cur.hasClass(classes[index])) {
             cur.removeClass('hidden');
          }
      });
   });
});
```

Whole solution in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BMT4x/

Comment: Using the functions of your solution, would there be a way to create a "Select All" button that, when clicked, would show all the data or hide the data, depending on what's selected?

Comment: Here is an example of how a select all button would look, but $(".select_all").click breaks $(".toggler").click: http://jsfiddle.net/BMT4x/1/

Comment: I created a new Question for my "toggle all" dilemma.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21320946/how-do-i-toggle-specific-element-classes-and-also-toggle-all-elements

Answer (score 0):

You cannot unconditionally toggle elements based on a click on one of the button filters if it is possible for an element to satisfy multiple filters at once. The correct approach is a little more involved.

Since your `checked` class means that only items corresponding to that button should be shown, do exactly this: toggle them based on the current status of the button. The items should be shown if and only if the corresponding button is `checked` as a result of clicking it.

```
$('#easy').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass( "checked" );
    $('.easy').toggle($(this).is(".checked"));
});
```

This code uses the last version of [`.toggle`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/), the one accepting a boolean argument.

It can also be done more succintly:

```
$('.easy').toggle($(this).toggleClass( "checked" ).is(".checked"));
```

Comment: I actually need the opposite: When a button is "checked", line items with the corresponding class should be visible. I updated the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/a4NkN/4/ ... Thanks...

Comment: @user2888697: I updated the answer to reflect this, it's just a matter of inverting the condition.