# How do I "toggle all", and also toggle specific classes of elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, logic, toggle

I want to toggle the visibility of classes of list items and also toggle the visibility of all the list items. With help of [another stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21269485/conditional-jquery-toggle-function), I am able to toggle specific classes of list items.

Here's the Javascript I have that toggles specific classes of list items:

```
var switcher = [false, false, false];
var classes = ['easy', 'fun', 'silly'];

$('.toggler').click(function () {
    var x = $(this).hasClass('checked');
    switcher[$(this).data('switch')] = !x;
    $(this).toggleClass("checked", !x);
    $('li').each(function () {
        var cur = $(this);
        cur.addClass('hidden');
        $.each(switcher, function (index, data) {
            if (data && cur.hasClass(classes[index])) {
                cur.removeClass('hidden');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I added the basic functionality to hide and show all the list items, but the function brakes the individual class toggles:

```
$('.select_all').click(function () {
    $(".toggler").toggleClass("checked");
    $('li').toggleClass("hidden");
});
```

How can I keep class toggles, and add another button that toggles all the items?

Here's a fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/BMT4x/1/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you're trying to do, but it should give you a push in the right direction (at least the direction I'd go). I prefer toggling everything with classes. Something like:

```
<button class="toggler" data-class="easy">Easy</button>,
<button class="toggler" data-class="fun">Fun</button>,
<button class="toggler" data-class="silly">Silly</button>,
<button class="toggler" data-class="all">Select All</button>


<ul id="list">
    <li class="easy">Bowling</li>
    <li class="fun">Balooning</li>
    <li class="fun easy">Boating</li>
    <li class="silly">Barfing</li>
    <li class="easy fun">Bafooning</li>
</ul>
```

The CSS:

```
#list li {
    display: none;
}
#list.easy li.easy {
    display: block;
}
#list.fun li.fun {
    display: block;
}
#list.silly li.silly {
    display: block;
}
#list.all li {
    display: block;
}
```

The JS:

```
$('.toggler').click(function () {
    var category = $(this).data('class');
    $('#list').toggleClass(category);
});
```

And a fiddle for reference: http://jsfiddle.net/qLLYj/

Comment: I think you may have forgotten to add the "all" class to the `li` elements?

Comment: @VIDesignz well, if it's showing them all... they don't need a class haha.

Comment: I'm just saying that the toggle all button does nothing based on your script. That's all...

Comment: @VIDesignz yes it does... `#list.all li { display: block; }`

Comment: Oooh..I see! I think I was expecting the Toggle All button to either show everything or hide everything when clicked (back and forth). My bad

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitly add/remove a class by passing a second, `switch`, parameter to `toggleClass` [(see here)](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/#toggleClass-className-switch).

So, you can change the state of all the individual switches and list items when clicking the `.select_all` button.

```
$('.select_all').click(function () {
    $('.select_all').toggleClass("checked");
    var allChecked = $('.select_all').hasClass("checked");
    switcher = [allChecked, allChecked, allChecked];
    $(".toggler").toggleClass("checked", allChecked);
    $('li').toggleClass("hidden", !allChecked);
});
```

Some further changes made to get more intuitive behaviour
(e.g. if all checked, clicking one of the toggles deselects `.select_all` as well as itself; checking all individual toggles means .select_all is automatically checked):

```
$('.toggler').click(function () {
    var x = $(this).hasClass('checked');
    switcher[$(this).data('switch')] = !x;
    $(this).toggleClass("checked");
    $('li').each(function () {
        var cur = $(this);
        cur.addClass('hidden');
        $.each(switcher, function (index, data) {
            if (data && cur.hasClass(classes[index])) {
                cur.removeClass('hidden');
            }
        });
    });

    var allChecked = switcher.indexOf(false) < 0;
    $('.select_all').toggleClass("checked", allChecked);
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ET33B/